# How do I properly align this title in Bootstrap/CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, responsive-design

I'm beginning to mock-up a WordPress theme based on Twitter's Bootstrap framework.
Could someone validate the code I have so far is kosher?

More specifically, the header...
I have my name and sub-head beside an avatar image.
I want the text to appear vertically in the middle of the image. This works successfully when the page is wide enough (screengrab: imgur.com/YCpSm). But, when I reduce the browser width and responsive design kicks in, the text moves up (screengrab: imgur.com/K4Vyj).

How do I ensure the text stays in the vertical center of the image?

Thanks.

--

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/robertandrews/jP4nT/ (contains standard bootstrap.css, standard bootstrap-responsive.css and custom CSS in one)

Page: http://jsfiddle.net/robertandrews/jP4nT/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

You could go with floating elements instead of absolute positioning:
http://jsfiddle.net/jP4nT/1/

I also wouldn't place the <h1> tag within the <p>, but that's probably fine though.

Comment: In your code, the adjacent text flows under the pic when the browser window is contracted. It should stay on the right.

Comment: You're right. How about this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jP4nT/2/
You can add more media-queries, if you need your design to work on even smaller screens. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/6FMDR/

- No extra html tags needed
- Less css

**CSS:**

```
.myheader {
  padding:15px 0 20px;
  display:block;
}

.myheader img {
   float: left;
   padding:0 15px 10px 0;    
}

.myheader h1 {
   margin-top: 10px;
}
```